# Hibernate has returns the zero results but native sql returns different

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle, hibernate, hibernate3

I wanted to know why I have different results hibernait query and sql? Have I wrong mapping? Java an hibernate hasn't an exceptions. I use in this case the Oracle 11 database and hibernate 3.5.

I have the next hibernate entity:

```
@Table(name = "pat_otb_registry")
public class OtbEntity implements Comparable<OtbEntity> {

    @Column(name = "legal_address_region")
    private BigDecimal legalAddressRegion;

    @Column(name = "declarant")
    private String declarant;

    @Column(name = "registry_cert_number")
    private String registryCertNumber;

    @Column(name = "decision_to_grant_date")
    private Date decisionToGrantDate;

    @Column(name = "competent_authority")
    private BigDecimal competentAuthority;

    @Column(name = "expiry_date")
    private Date expiryDate;

    @Column(name = "decision_to_grant_number")
    private String decisionToGrantNumber;

    @Column(name = "decision_to_cancel_number")
    private String decisionToCancelNumber;

    @Column(name = "decision_to_exclude_number")
    private String decisionToExcludeNumber;

    @Column(name = "certification_authority")
    private String certificationAuthority;

    @Column(name = "appraisee")
    private String appraisee;

    @Column(name = "date_of_end_stage")
    private Date dateOfEndStage;

    @Column(name = "certification_field")
    private String certificationField;

    @Column(name = "validity_years")
    private BigDecimal validityYears;

    @Column(name = "decision_to_extend_number")
    private String decisionToExtendNumber;

    @Column(name = "issue_date")
    private Date issueDate;

    @Column(name = "reason")
    private String reason;

    @Column(name = "decision_to_cancel_date")
    private Date decisionToCancelDate;

    @Column(name = "decision_to_exclude_date")
    private Date decisionToExcludeDate;

    @Column(name = "decision_to_extend_date")
    private Date decisionToExtendDate;

    @Column(name = "extended_to_date")
    private Date extendedToDate;

    @Column(name = "oa_registry_number")
    private String oaRegistryNumber;

    @Column(name = "grounds_for_issue")
    private String groundsForIssue;

    @Column(name = "doc_num")
    private String docNum;
// then getters and setters....
}
```

The SQL Table:

```
CREATE TABLE pat_otb_registry (
    legal_address_region number(10,0)  NULL,
    declarant nvarchar2(2000)  NOT NULL,
    registry_cert_number nvarchar2(2000)  NOT NULL,
    decision_to_grant_date date  NULL,
    competent_authority smallint  NOT NULL,
    expiry_date date  NULL,
    decision_to_grant_number nvarchar2(2000)  NULL,
    decision_to_cancel_number nvarchar2(2000)  NULL,
    decision_to_exclude_number nvarchar2(2000)  NULL,
    certification_authority nvarchar2(2000)  NOT NULL,
    appraisee varchar2(2000)  NOT NULL,
    date_of_end_stage date  NULL,
    certification_field nvarchar2(2000)  NULL,
    validity_years integer  NULL,
    decision_to_extend_number nvarchar2(2000)  NULL,
    issue_date date  NULL,
    reason nvarchar2(2000)  NULL,
    decision_to_cancel_date date  NULL,
    decision_to_exclude_date date  NULL,
    decision_to_extend_date date  NULL,
    extended_to_date date  NULL,
    oa_registry_number nvarchar2(2000)  NULL,
    grounds_for_issue nvarchar2(2000)  NULL,
    doc_num nvarchar2(2000)  NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pat_otb_registry_pk PRIMARY KEY (registry_cert_number)
) ;
```

the hibernate query:

```
getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT o FROM " + getEntityName() + " o").getResultList()
```

SQL query:

```
getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("select * from pat_otb_registry")
```

Comment: Apart that I dont see your @Id annotation for the primary key it looks ok to me. I dont have the patience to check all the column names , but I presume if there was wrong naming it should complain during deploy.

Comment: Some examples of you native SQL query and hibernate requests would definitely help to understand the issue

Comment: Gut feel tells me it will be related to the choice/reason for using an NVARCHAR2 column for a primary key. What are all the relevant character sets involved ?

Comment: Please append both hibernate and native SQL queries to the question.

Comment: There is no @Id becose is table only for reading, I have check all names, and names are equals...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a bug. I have not worked properly EntityManager - getEntityManager()